# Android App Dev: any example/suggestion on how to code audio stream of file from a remote ftp server?

Tags: android, file, audio, ftp, stream

Working on an android app to stream music from my ftp server, I was wondering if anyone can offer any code, advice, or tutorial on how to access the specific folder/directory containing the audio files, list the audio files, and stream them through my app, also if it is possible or not. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like [this](http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/) be helpful? For accessing the data via FTP, the [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net//apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) class could become handy.

Comment: Thanks @LostAvatar, I've fixed this issue. The answer you provide is basically the same process, you read from the stream onto a temp file and when download is complete you play it. You add a buffer to adjust for read vs write speed. using FTP Client to initiate your connection and the connection parameters you enter should be fixed on the server to allow access to specifc folder with media files only.

Comment: First link in answer is dead.